# $f:[0,\infty )\rightarrow [0,\infty )$ be a continuous function.What is the fastest way to check if f is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty )\rightarrow [0,\infty )$  be a continuous function.Which of the following conditions ensure that f is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty )$ and what is the fastest way to check this?

$a.$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ f(x)}{x^2}=0$

$b.$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x}f(x)=0$

$c.$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(\sin (x))=0$

$d.$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(e^x)=0$

Comment: Have you done any work yourself?

Answer (score 0):

a. $f(x)= x\sin x$ is not uniformly continuous.

c. The limit is not even defined as for many $x$, $\sin x$ fails to be in the domain of $f$. Anyway, this only shows that $f(0)=0$ for all $x$ with $|x|\le 1$ (why?).

b. implies, and d. is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, and this implies uniform continuity: Given $\epsilon>0$ pick $x_0$ such that $|f(x)|<\frac12\epsilon$ for $x>x_0$. On the compact set $[0,x_0+1]$, $f$ is uniformly continuous, hence for $x$ in this interval, there exists a suitable $\delta>0$, wlog. $\delta<1$. This $\delta$ works for all of$[0,\infty)$.

Comment: $x\sin x$ is uniformly continuous. It has a bounded derivative on $[0,\infty)$. A better example would be $x\sqrt{x}$. Also, the sentence "$f(0)=0$ for all $x$ with $|x|\le 1$" makes no sense.